# Does the the dynamic array need to be deleted or deallocated if the return is not assigned? Or is it deleted by the function?

Tags: c++, arrays, memory, dynamic

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int *arrExpand(int *arr, int arrSize)
{
    int *p = new int [arrSize * 2];
    for(int i =0; i < arrSize * 2; i++)
    {   if(i < arrSize)
            p[i] = arr[i];
        if(i > arrSize)
            p[i] = 0;
    }
    return p;
}

int main()
{
    int mySize = 5;
    int myArr[5] = {1,2,3,4,5};

    cout << "Array: ";
    for(auto v: myArr)
        cout << v;
    for( int i = 0; i < mySize * 2; i++)
        cout  << endl << *(arrExpand(myArr,mySize)+i);
    //return is not assigned == delete not needed?
    return 0;
}
```

Does the function delete and deallocate the memory since the return is not assigned?
Does the memory need to be deallocated?

Comment: Look this up: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: Yes, it needs to be deleted.

If you allocate objects with `new`, you should also delete them. Using plain pointers is error-prone and a lot of manual work, this is why C++ has several smart pointers available, most importantly [`std::unique_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr) and [`std::shared_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr). In your case `std::unique_ptr` might be an option.

Example:

```
std::unique_ptr<int[]> arrExpand(int *arr, int arrSize)
{
    std::unique_ptr<int[]> p( new int [arrSize * 2] );
    for(int i =0; i < arrSize * 2; i++)
    {   if(i < arrSize)
            p[i] = arr[i];
        if(i > arrSize)
            p[i] = 0;
    }
    return std::move(p);
}
```

Which can be used in your example like this:

```
auto result = arrExpand(myArr,mySize);
for( int i = 0; i < mySize * 2; i++)
    cout  << endl << result[i];
```

Note that you should store the result of `arrExpand` once *before* the loop, otherwise the function will be called for each iteration of the loop which is quite inefficient.

Comment: Where would I place the delete if its not assigned? before the return 0?

Comment: @tariqebadi That's the reason to use smart pointers: You don't have to call `delete`, they will take care of it. When you use a `std::unique_ptr` like I showed, you are mostly safe and there will be no resource leaks - even in case of exceptions.

Answer (score 4):

As already mentioned, you do indeed need to `delete[]` the memory. You can just remember this simple rule:

> `delete` everything you `new`ed *exactly* once. The same applies to `delete[]` and `new[]`.

I do however not agree with the smart-pointer advice. While `std::unique_ptr` would have some advantages as drop-in replacement for raw arrays in large, old codebases (as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28238510/3002139)), the much more natural alternative is [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector):

```
std::vector<int> arrExpand(int *arr, int arrSize)
{
    std::vector<int> p (arrSize * 2);
    for(int i =0; i < arrSize * 2; i++)
    {   if(i < arrSize)
            p[i] = arr[i];
        if(i > arrSize)
            p[i] = 0;
    }
    return p;
}
```

or even better

```
std::vector<int> arrExpand(const std::vector<int> &arr)
{
    std::vector<int> p (arr.size() * 2);
    for(int i =0; i < arr.size() * 2; i++)
    {   if(i < arr.size())
            p[i] = arr[i];
        if(i > arr.size())
            p[i] = 0;
    }
    return p;
}
```

It is generally (at least I do not know a counter-example) a very good idea to use `std::vector` as your standard runtime-sized array. One good reason is the automatic and correct memory management. It also comes with quite a few useful member functions, including knowing its own size.